# xUnit Theory with async MemberData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, xunit.net

I have a unit test project using [xUnit.net](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core) v.2.3.1 for my ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app.

My test should focus on testing a given DataEntry instance: DataEntry instances are generated by the async method GenerateData() in my DataService class, which looks like:

```
public class DataService {
    ...
    public async Task<List<DataEntry>> GenerateData() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I am writing this test case as a Theory so my test can focus on a DataEntry instance at a time. Here is the code:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetDataEntries))]
public void Test_DataEntry(DataEntry entry) {

    // my assertions
    Assert.NotNull(entry);
    ...

}

public static async Task<IEnumerable<object[]>> GetDataEntries() {

    var service = new DataService();
    List<DataEntry> entries = await service.GenerateData().ConfigureAwait(false);

    return entries.Select(e => new object[] { e });

}
```

However, I get the following error at compile time:

> MemberData must reference a data type assignable to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object[]>'. The referenced type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object[]>>' is not valid.

From the error description, it seems [xUnit.net](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core) does not allow MemberData to use an async static method, like my GetDataEntries() one. Is there any functionality gap in [xUnit.net](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core) I should be aware of?

Now, I know I could switch my Theory into a Fact and loop through each DataEntry in the list returned by my DataService, however I would prefer to keep a Theory setup as my test would be cleaner and focused on DataEntry instead of List<DataEntry>.

**Question**: is there any way in [xUnit.net](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core) to let my Theory get data from my DataService async API? Please, note the DataService class cannot be changed nor extended to provide data synchronously.

### EDIT

I am looking for a way through async/await and would prefer to avoid any usage of blocking calls such as Task<T>.Result e.g. on my GenerateData() method, as the underlying thread will be blocked til the operation completes.
This is relevant in my test project as I have other similar test cases where data should be retrieved in the same way and therefore I want to avoid ending up with too many blocking calls, but instead keeping the async/await propagation.

Comment: I don't know how this will play out, but try `.Result` on your `GenerateData`.

Comment: thanks for the input, but I would actually prefer to find a way through async/await as, by using Task<T>.Result, the underlying Thread will be blocked til the operation completes. In general, this would be fine if it was an isolated scenario, but I actually have several other similar test cases where I need to retrieve data from an asynchronous call like the one I posted and therefore I want to avoid ending up with too many blocking calls.

Comment: @PauloMorgado from your comment I just realized my question was not precise enough, hence I just edited.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, I just tried and it works: using `.Result` removes the need of using Task as my static member GetDataEntries() would end up returning type IEnumerable<object[]> instead of Task<IEnumerable<object[]>>.

Comment: issue reference in the xUnit repository: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1698

Comment: AFAIK from reading [link](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/) there is no support for async methods and the error message supports my theory. You only can use "sync" methods.
Perhaps look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/593045) how to get a synchronous method from an async method.

Answer (score 2):

Until xUnit allows async theory data, you can use `Task<T>` instances as theory data and await them inside the test method (note that test methods *can* be async):

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetDataEntries() {
    var service = new DataService();
    yield return new object[] { service.GenerateData() };
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetDataEntries))]
public async Task Test_DataEntry(Task<List<DataEntry>> task) {
    List<DataEntry> entries = await task;

    for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++) {
        // my assertions
        Assert.NotNull(entries[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not provided internally. You can try following:

1. Write your *CustomMemberDataAttribute* by inheriting *DataAttribute*.
2. Override 'GetData' method of parent class.
3. Make the method async, that, provides data.
4. Call async data provider method from 'GetData' method.
5. Use your *CustomMemberDataAttribute* to decorate test cases.

You can refer following link to write your custom attribute.
Keep other method same, just modify 'GetData' method as discuss above.
https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/bccfcccf26b2c63c90573fe1a17e6572882ef39c/src/xunit.core/MemberDataAttributeBase.cs